# Registo de formulário

Tags: php

Pretendo criar um serviço de registo de utilizadores em php e Mysql phpmyadmin
no entanto o meu código insere.php não está a inserir os registos no phpmyadmin e não estou a perceber onde estou a errar no código, já testei com $S_POST e testei como $S_GET e nada.

o código do formulario.php e insere.php são os seguintes:

código insere.php:

```
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: formulario.php");
}
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "admin", "usersregistados");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$error = false;

if (isset($_POST['Inserir'])) {

    // Prevent SQL Injection

    $username = trim($_GET['username']);
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $username = htmlspecialchars($username);

    $password = trim($_GET['password']);
    $password = strip_tags($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

    $email = trim($_GET['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    // Check username
    if (empty($username)) {
        $error         = true;
        $usernameError = "Please fill in this field!";
    } else {
        // Does email address exist?
        $query  = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count != 0) {
            $error         = true;
            $usernameError = "Username is taken!";
        }
    }

    // Check email
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error      = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
    } else {
        // Does email address exist?
        $query  = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($query);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count != 0) {
            $error      = true;
            $emailError = "Email is already in use!";
        }
    }

    // password validation
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error     = true;
        $passError = "Please fill in this field!";
    } else if (strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error     = true;
        $passError = "Field must contain at least 6 characters!";
    }

    // password encrypt using SHA256();
    $password = hash('sha256', $password);

    // if there's no error, continue to signup
    if (!$error) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}')";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

        if ($res) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
            unset($name);
            unset($email);
            unset($pass);
        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

código formulario.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        </form>
        <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container has-text-centered">
                    <img src="ipcb_logo.png" height="40" width="150">
                    <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
                        <h3 class="title has-text-grey">Formulário de Registo</h3>
                        <div class="box">
                            <form action="insere.php" method="POST">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input name="username" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Username" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input name="password" class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input name="email" name="text" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <butto>
                                        <p>
                                            <input name="inserir" class="button is-block is-link is-large is-fullwidth" type="submit" value="Inserir" </p>
                                            </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <img src="produtech_logo.png" height="40" width="300" align="middle"></p>
                        <br>
                        <img src="Logo_financiamento.png" height="40" width="300" align="middle"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
    </body>

    </html><?php
session_start();
?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        </form>
        <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
            <div class="hero-body">
                <div class="container has-text-centered">
                    <img src="ipcb_logo.png" height="40" width="150">
                    <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
                        <h3 class="title has-text-grey">Formulário de Registo</h3>
                        <div class="box">
                            <form action="insere.php" method="POST">
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input name="username" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Username" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input name="password" class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="field">
                                    <div class="control">
                                        <input name="email" name="text" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <button>
                                        <p>
                                            <input name="inserir" class="button is-block is-link is-large is-fullwidth" type="submit" value="Inserir" </p>
                                            </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <img src="produtech_logo.png" height="40" width="300" align="middle"></p>
                        <br>
                        <img src="Logo_financiamento.png" height="40" width="300" align="middle"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dei uma corrigida no seu código e vamos por partes. Começando no HTML tem-se alguns erros, primeiramente tem uma tag form sendo fechada porém sem ser aberta anteriormente. Exatamente onde mostrado a baixo:

```
    <body>
    </form>
    <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
```

Segundo o input email apresenta dois atributos name, sendo que o segundo provavelmente seria um atributo type:

```
<input name="email" name="text" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus="">
```

Terceiro e o que contribuiu para não funcionar foi a parte onde se encontra o botão:

```
  <butto>                                        
      <p>
          <input name="inserir" class="button is-block is-link is-large is-fullwidth" type="submit" value="Inserir" </p>
                                        </button>
```

Na tag button falta a letra n, o input inserir é um outro botão (preste atenção pois aqui que está o problema), além da tag input inserir não ser fechada.

Agora vamos a parte de inserção:
Note que você espera que exista um input inserir, passado como POST:

```
if (isset($_POST['Inserir'])) {
```

Porém o input inserir não é enviado uma vez que foi setado seu tipo como submit, o que faz que se não se envie o seu valor pela requisição. Além de que o input está com o name inserir(minúsculo) e na verificação está maiúsculo. Ou seja, nunca entraria nessa verificação. Para corrigir basta tirar o input inserir de dentro do botão, e mudar seu tipo para hidden, assim ele não aparece no formulário e é possível recuperá-lo na variável post, e trocando a função de botão para tag button, assim:

```
<div class="input-group">                            
  <input name="inserir" type="hidden"   value="Inserir"> 
  <button class="button is-block is-link is-large is-fullwidth" type="submit">Inserir 
  </button>                                
</div>
```

Ai a sua verificação no insere.php fica assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['inserir'])) {
```

Por último não menos importante, a função mysqli_query, espera como primeiro parâmetro a instância da conexão da base de dados, você passou somente a query em si em duas linhas.

Aqui:

```
 // Does email address exist?
    $query  = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($query);
```

E aqui:

```
// Does email address exist?
$query  = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

Corrigidas ficariam assim:

```
 // Does email address exist?
    $query  = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

E assim:

```
// Does email address exist?
$query  = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Além de trocar também os $_GET por $_POST.

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $username = htmlspecialchars($username);

    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $password = strip_tags($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
```

Finalizando seguem os códigos completos corrigidos para você testar, testei aqui e funcionaram:
 formulario.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bulma.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/login.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section class="hero is-success is-fullheight">
        <div class="hero-body">
            <div class="container has-text-centered">
                <img src="ipcb_logo.png" height="40" width="150">
                <div class="column is-4 is-offset-4">
                    <h3 class="title has-text-grey">Formulário de Registo</h3>
                    <div class="box">
                        <form action="insere.php" method="POST">
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input name="username" type="text" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Username" autofocus="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input name="password" class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Your Password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <div class="control">
                                    <input name="email" type="email" class="input is-large" placeholder="Your Email" autofocus="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">

                                        <input name="inserir" type="hidden"   value="Inserir"> 
                                <button class="button is-block is-link is-large is-fullwidth" type="submit">Inserir </button>                                

                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <img src="produtech_logo.png" height="40" width="300" align="middle"></p>
                    <br>
                    <img src="Logo_financiamento.png" height="40" width="300" align="middle"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

insere.php:

```
    <?php
ob_start();
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
    header("Location: formulario.php");
}
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usersregistados");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$error = false;

if (isset($_POST['inserir'])) {

    // Prevent SQL Injection

    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $username = htmlspecialchars($username);

    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $password = strip_tags($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);


    // Check username
    if (empty($username)) {
        $error         = true;
        $usernameError = "Please fill in this field!";
    } else {
        // Does email address exist?
        $query  = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='{$username}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count != 0) {
            $error         = true;
            $usernameError = "Username is taken!";
        }
    }


    // Check email
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error      = true;
        $emailError = "Please enter valid email address.";
    } else {
        // Does email address exist?
        $query  = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='{$email}'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($count != 0) {
            $error      = true;
            $emailError = "Email is already in use!";
        }
    }

    // password validation
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error     = true;
        $passError = "Please fill in this field!";
    } else if (strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error     = true;
        $passError = "Field must contain at least 6 characters!";
    }

    // password encrypt using SHA256();
    $password = hash('sha256', $password);

    // if there's no error, continue to signup
    if (!$error) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('{$username}', '{$password}', '{$email}')";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

        if ($res) {
            $errTyp = "success";
            $errMSG = "Successfully registered, you may login now";
            unset($name);
            unset($email);
            unset($pass);
        } else {
            $errTyp = "danger";
            $errMSG = "Something went wrong, try again later...";
        }

    }


}
?>
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda, funcionou a introdução de users com a encriptação da password, mas quando o codigo executa as verificações não mostras as mensagens, mas também não deixa registar se houver um user, password e email já registado na base de dados.

Comment: Para persistir as mensagens de erro e mostra-las no formulário será necessário salva-las em variáveis de sessão. Ao constatar um erro, retorna ao formulário e verifica se existem variáveis de sessão com a chave error por exemplo e as exibe. Neste link fala um pouco mais sobre as sessões: [link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Debugue a aplicação utilizando as funções var_dump(nome_var) e exit. Assim você consegue verificar se a execução está chegando em determinado ponto. Pode ser problema nas verificações if.

Comment: Já está resolvido!!!! Valeu a ajuda de todos